How do Star Whales access hyperspace?
During the Disney+ series, Ahsoka, part of the plot involves Ahsoka utilizing what she (and other characters later) calls Star Whales.
These Star Whales are able to access hyperspace and transport Ahsoka and her ship to another galaxy to pursue the antagonist. Once there the group of Star Whales are besieged and make a hasty exit again through hyperspace.
I don't recall an explanation being given in the Ahsoka series about how the whales are able to access hyperspace, but I know that this series continues plot lines from Star Wars: Rebels animated series (which I have not seen).
I suspect that the ability has something to do with the Force, but is there any explanation given within show canon or from other sources (interviews, encyclopedias, novels, etc.)?

I just think it is an evolutionary trait they acquired over thousands/millions of years to be able to migrate like birds.

Per the Solo: A Star Wars Story - The Official Guide factbook, Purrgills (AKA "Space Whales") are able to access hyperspace through a natural process of metabolism of a gas called Clouzon-36.

OLD AND NEW DISCOVERIES
Refined coaxium is a far cry from the natural form of the substance.
Ancient spacefarers discovered coaxium in the organs of purrgil—huge
space-traveling creatures. The purrgil inhale space gases containing
traces of the gas Clouzon-36, which they metabolize into a hypermatter
fuel. This enables them to jump into hyperspace.

Purrgills are the species that introduced early humans to hyperspatial travel, appearing seemingly at random in various colonised star system.

Purrgil are massive whale-like creatures that live in the vacuum of
deep space. But what makes them especially unique is their natural
ability to access hyperspace, as seen in Star Wars Rebels. Purrgil
introduced sentients of the galaxy to hyperspace and inspired them to
create hyperdrives in order to travel to the alternate dimension that
these amazing creatures could inexplicably reach.
In Star Wars Rebels when Jedi Padawan Ezra Bridger first discovers the majestic purrgil, he connects with one and sees the swirl of hyperspace in its eye. What Ezra is seeing in this moment, and what ships see as they travel through the iconic spiral of blues in hyperspace, is called a simu-tunnel. A simu-tunnel is what hyperspace look like when you’re safely contained in a hyperdrive-produced pocket of realspace while traveling through hyperspace. Purrgil create them naturally.
StarWars.com - Star Wars Inside Intel: Hyperspace


I shudder to imagine what evolutionary pressures would make hyperspace travel a necessary trait. Is their main predator Galactus?

@MiloP - There's always a bigger fish....

Space Sharks, of course. (And now I want to reread Glen Cook's Starfishers trilogy)

@clvrmnky Orcas are pretty small whales. In fact they predate on larger whales themselves.

Great answer per usual. I am shocked the Force wasn't involved!

@Skooba - As usual, I've tried to see if midi-chlorians were involved somehow, or if I can use the Top Trumps game as a source. Alas, in both cases the answer is no.
